AWS CodeCommit: How to list all users with access to a certain repo?
My organization has around 200 users and we are fixing all the security permissions on our AWS cloud infraestructure, my boss assigned me to check codecommit, so i need to list all the users that have access to AWS CodeCommit
I have found that i need to use IAM, but there are a lot of policies all over, is there a way to filter all the policies that apply to codecommit and then all the users asigned to them?
thanks...

Aside from writing a custom app, you might investigate third party utilities such as this or this but make sure you're comfortable in the security of these apps first.
